# Generators for polynomials annd multiplicative inverses, not sure what is going on here $X^{-3}$ becomes $X^{12}$. How?

Tags: polynomials

I am confused on this problem. I am not sure what is happening with the (-3) for it to become (12), to then become a larger polynomial in a GF type of problem.

Here is more information about the problem. I hope it helps, but I don't have an actual problem per se. It's more of a concept I want to understand.

[image]

Can someone explain why they are doing that calculation with the multiplicative inverses please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think we may need to read the actual problem text as well. Without that, we can guess, but even we will be somewhat uncertain as to what's actually going on.

Comment: Let me see if I can find it in the book. Thank you.

Comment: I added more context for the problem. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are in $GF(2^n)$, with $n=4$.  It is the splitting field of $x^{16}-x$.  Thus $g^{15}=1$ (or $g^{-3}=g^{12}$).

Comment: One doesn't actually need the notion of splitting field for this. In a field of $q$ elements, the multiplicative group of non-zero elements has $q-1$ elements. So by Lagrange's theorem from group theory, all its elements satisfy $x^{q-1}=1$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass  Nice.  Thanks for that insight.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.